# In Emscripten C++ / wbasm how does one get an "on page closed" event

Tags: html, emscripten

I have  C+ program that compiles to web assebmbly using the emscripten system.  I would like to clean up some things, flush files, etc etc. when he page running the program is closed.

in main there is:

```
emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(onMainLoopTick, arg, 0, 1);
```

Currently when the page closes the "process" is simply exited and does not continue after the "loop simulator".  I figure I need to get an event from the page that will block the main thread until the C++ code process it and cleans up it's mess.

What event should I forward to C++ and how should I use it ?

Comment: Do you mean you want something like atexit() or SIGINT handler when the page is closed?

Comment: @BumsikKim  functionally yes, BUT that isn't supported in a browser environment.  I'm assuming I have to subscribe to an event on the main thread and pass it into the C++ code or provide a callback to a canned emscripten provided method, but I can't find a doc about shutdown/sleep/etc sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first things to know is that there is no native library nor APIs for WebAssembly (I mean..yet, [as of MVP. There are native features like threads coming as post-MVP feature](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/10/webassemblys-post-mvp-future/)). What is means that all system libraries in C++ are implemented by importing emulated JavaScript functions. So if you are looking for native features like detecting closing events, you should check if there is JS/HTML5 APIs that do the similar things.

To see how it works, open generated `.wast` file and search for [`import` instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format#Importing_functions_from_JavaScript) and generated JS files. Also, you may want to search on [Emscripten repo](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) directly to check if there is JS/HTML5 bindings available on C++ side, as their documentation is quite large and hard to look through.

Sticking to the point, the HTML5 events that are fired when closing are [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) and [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload). I would prefer using `beforeunload` event. Emscripten provides `em_beforeunload_callback` callback function type and `emscripten_set_beforeunload_callback` to register in [html5.h bindings](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html).

Otherwise, you use them directly. For example:

In C++:

```
void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE clean_stuff() {
    // Clean up the mess...
    // You should use EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE or
    // add it to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS in emcc compilation options
    // to make it callable in JS side.
}
```

In JS:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    // Exported functions are prefixed by an underscore
    Module._clean_stuff();
});
```

Comment: Yes I knew that but was wondering if the EMSDK had already set up a canned ability to do this and/or had "an official recommended" best practice here. Their (js) code already adds listeners to some dom objects. I implemented an exported function in our code and put in JS listeners on the DOM window for unload and beforeunload, and added listeners first before any EMSDK inserted listeners and am getting what I need. And so far (fingers crossed) so good. :)

Comment: @peterk Yeah although EMSDK has html5.js for it as I mentioned, I would preper adding the listener myself like you did. From my experience Emscripten's documentation hardly ever suggests clear "good practice" nor comprehensive examples, and its API seems to change a lot without notice (especially when it comes to setting "Module" object by myself). I can understand that cuz the whole Webassembly ecosystem is not stable yet. At least their source code are not theoretically complicated so it is quite easy to figure out their intentions hind the source code.